# Get order id less than 90 days back by checking dateof purchase value in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, date, stored-procedures

```
SELECT c.orderId 
FROM OrderDetails c 
WHERE Date_of_Purchase > DATEADD(NOW(), INTERVAL - 90 DAY)
```

I need to get orderId of orders with a dateofpurchase less than 90 days from today

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be mixing MySQL and SQL Server syntax. In SQL Server, you can do:

```
SELECT c.orderId 
FROM OrderDetails c 
WHERE Date_of_Purchase > DATEADD(d, -90, getdate())
```

This gives you records whose date is less than 90 days from the current date *and* time. If you want 90 days from today (whitout the time component):

```
SELECT c.orderId 
FROM OrderDetails c 
WHERE Date_of_Purchase > DATEADD(d, -90, cast(getdate() as date))
```